# removing pkg installation

Tags: install, pkg

Is it possible to remove all that was installed by a pkg installer? I read that "When a package is installed, it creates a “receipt” which contains details about what files and directories were created." But does this "receipt" always all details about what files were created or is this creation up to the pkg file (thus its developer)?
My problem is that when i install some pkg, i want to make sure that even if it contains some spying "crap" that it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The .pkg might well contain all the information about directories and files that were created by the installer.

But this is not of much use for malware because running one of those files can create directories and other files and the installer and so the .pkg file will not know anything about them.

So the answer is probably yes for a well behaved app but no for malware.